# "Use default container" doesn't show in iCloud Capabilities

Tags: swift, icloud, cloudkit

I want set up `iCloud` sync for `CoreData` using `CloudKit`.

But when I add `iCloud` in `Capabilities` and enable `CloudKit` checkbox, `Use default container` don't appear as described in the Doc:
 [image: Capabilities tab]

Instead, I got this:

[image: have no “Use default container”]
Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This changed in Xcode 11, there no longer is a default container checkbox.

Instead you have to create your own container. Just press the + and enter your bundle-id. Xcode will automatically prefix it with `iCloud.`

So the result will be `iCloud.<your app’s bundle ID>`, the same as the default Xcode used previously.

This seems to be a useful tutorial, updated with changes in Xcode 11: https://www.raywenderlich.com/4878052-cloudkit-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: "The identifier for the default container matches the app’s bundle ID.", quoted from the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH2-SW1).