# What's happened to the default iCloud container in Xcode

Tags: xcode, icloud

This screen shot from the WWDC 2019 video 202 shows what the iCloud capability configuration in Xcode should look like:

[image]

The problem is that it doesn't. In the current version of Xcode 11 (11.1 and later) I no longer see "Use default container", and I can't get a container for this app to magically create itself. All I see is a list of custom containers.

[image]

How is this supposed to work? Is there no such thing as a default container any more? Am I supposed to make a container manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather from Apple's response to my report on this, this change is intentional.

Comment: What was your solution to this - did you have to manually create a container?

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty weird because neither the [Xcode 11.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_1_release_notes) nor the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/mirroring_a_core_data_store_with_cloudkit/setting_up_core_data_with_cloudkit) mention any change.

Practically the *Default Container* was the implicitly created container `iCloud.$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)`.

Apparently Xcode 11.1 doesn't create a container anymore so you have to do it. Xcode doesn't even enable CloudKit in the capabilities after checking the CloudKit checkbox in a new project. I regard this as a bug.

Comment: Yes, it's as if the whole back-and-forth communication that you used to get just for turning on the iCloud capability now no longer happens. But it is not clear to me how to create a container correctly. I have filed a bug as well.

Comment: Well so far you was able to create as many custom containers as you want by clicking the plus button. The recommended form is `iCloud.com.something.somethingelse`. Xcode complains if the container name is invalid.